# How to navigate horizontally through cells in jqgrid on press of tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid 3.8.2 with a few columns in it.I want to navigate through these cells on pressing tab key and when it reaches last column, it should perform validation of the current row and then move to the next row and repeat the same.In the current grid I have, pressing tab on a cell,is saving that row and moving to the next row, instead of navigating through the remaining cells in the row.How do I accomplish the same? below is the function that gets called on tab key down.

```
function actionOnTabKeyDown(event)
    {  var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode;  
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        var nextRow = null;
        var validationStatus = null;     
        if (key == 9){
        { var currentDiv = event.target;
            for(var i= 0;i < ids.length;i++)
            {if(ids[i] == m_lastSelectedRow && (i != length - 1) )
                {nextRow = ids[i+1];
                 break;}}
           validationStatus = validateInput(m_lastSelectedRow);
           m_rowValidationStatus = validationStatus;
           if(validationStatus == 'pass') 
           {if(nextRow != null){   editRow(nextRow);m_lastSelectedRow = nextRow;}
               else{m_lastSelectedRow = null;}}        
           else if(validationStatus == 'ask')
           {
            //   alert("after validation ask");
               if(nextRow != null)
               {
                   nextSelectedRow = nextRow;
               } 
           }
           //if failed, keep the row as it is
        }//}
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks,
poorna.

Comment: where is the code? Please post relevant code....

Comment: have you gone through the docs?

Comment: Here is the function that is gettiong called on tab key press,

Comment: Here is the function that is getting called on tab key press,function actionOnTabKeyDown(event)
    {  var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode;  
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        var nextRow = null;
        var validationStatus = null;     
        if (key == 9){
        { var currentDiv = event.target;
   for(var i= 0;i < ids.length;i++)  {if(ids[i] == m_lastSelectedRow && (i != length - 1) {nextRow = ids[i+1]; break;}}
           validationStatus = validateInput(m_lastSelectedRow);
          m_rowValidationStatus = validationStatus;}

Comment: you should click on "edit" button below of the question. In the way you can modify the text of your question. You should append the code to the text of your question instead of posting it in the comment.

Comment: thanks @Oleg i have edited it.

Comment: Can someone please help on this?